# Posts variable empty

Tags: handlebars.js, blogs, ghost-blog

I followed the steps described in this post http://support.ghost.org/create-custom-page-template/ to create a custom page.

What I want to do in this page is show an Index of all my blog posts. Without description, just the header.

So, I created a static page that's on http://myadress/test
And create a page-test.hbs in my root folder. In this file I wrote this code to make a test:

```
{{!< default}}
<ol class="posts">
  {{#foreach posts}}
  <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>test</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
  {{/foreach}}
</ol>
  <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>test</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The code inside the foreach is no executed. But what's outside is.

Now, I'm new to Ghost, so probably the posts variable has nothing, right? How do I put the list of posts in there?

Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to put some post data/attributes in there. What you have done is just create the post scope .ie

```
{{title}} {{content}} {{published_at}} etc....
```

Take a look here for a list of all the attributes: [The post context](http://themes.ghost.org/docs/post-context#post-object-attributes)